# How do I attach a shower caddy to the shower pipe?

Tags: bathroom, shower

I rent an apartment that has this shower. I put a shower caddy underneath to hold the shampoo.

[image]

But the problem is that the caddy keeps sliding off. I've tried taping it to the tiles, but eventually it always comes off. What can I do so that it stays put?

Comment: Wrap some tape around the shower arm so that the clamp can't slide forward.

Comment: I've done the tape thing in the past. Works well. Wrap a bunch of duck tape on the caddy. Enough so that when you put it on it pinked the pipe and stays in place.

Comment: Pull the escutcheon forward and put it behind. Or bend the hanger so that it itself grips the pipe. Lift it up, squeeze it tighter, then pull it back down onto the pipe until it 'snaps' into place.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Suction cups are fairly standard for the problem you are trying to solve. **Shower suction cups** in your search engine of choice will find many, some ready to clip right on to the wires of your shampoo holder.

You could also put a cable tie or clamp on the shower arm to prevent or limit the slipping at that point

Tape will pretty much always lose against soap and hot water.

If your rope ends up slipping - A cable tie is plastic, so it won't rust or scratch your pipe, and far less expensive than a clamp. Anything longer than about 2.5" will fit a standard nominal 1/2" shower arm.

[image: Picture of a cable tie. Source was pipelagging in the UK, no endorsement, never heard of them before just wanted a simple picture after overly complex clamps were suggested in other answers.]

Comment: Hey that was a great idea! I tied a rope in front of it!

Comment: I use a zip tie for this exact purpose. (Voted)

Answer (score 12):

One of [these](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Gardner-Bender-1-in-Rubber-Insulated-Metal-Clamp-1-Pack-PPR-1600/202875644)

[image]

*General concept. You might need to get a different size.*

This thing wraps around the shower pipe on your side of the caddy. You run a bolt and nut through the hole to clamp it tight (if you sized it right there will be a 3/8" or 10mm gap give or take.

This clamp keeps the caddy from sliding down.

That metal is stainless steel. very important.  The rubber prevents scratching the chrome pipe, which could happen with an automotive hose clamp (those are also not all stainless and will rust).

The bolt I recommend is 1" (25mm) long **brass** bolt (machine screw) of thread 10-24 (or M4-0.7).  Also get a matching brass nut.  I suggest a family owned hardware store rather than Home Depot, because HD will sell you these in bags of 5 or 20, and the family store will sell you singles.

We've had ours at least 5 years with nothing but the normal tarnish that brass picks up.

Comment: HD's website lists 2 pack of the screws and a 6 pack of the nuts for $1.38 each.  The price is low enough transportation expenses and time will probably dominate the cost, so go with wherever is closer or easier for you to find things in.   And I'd want at least one spare anyway because if you only get 1 you're probably going to end up dropping it down the drain (or the fastener gremlins will gradually spin it off over the next 6 months) and needing to make a second trip.

Comment: It's called a P clip - and you'll need to check carefully to get stainless as many aren't.  You could also use a stainless screw and nut instead of brass

Answer (score 5):

Unless you have mirror like tile surface do not bother with suction cups. They will fall off.

Get proper size hose clamp at any hardware store.

Get it in Stainless Steal to prevent rust.

All you need is a screwdriver to instal.

Example

[image: clamp]

Answer (score 4):

While normal tape and adhesive doesn't work well in a wet environment, tapes and adhesives designed for wet environments work quite well. For example, 3M makes a set of Command products specifically for baths and showers, including adhesive strips and shower caddies - I've used these with great success. You could attach a hook around your shower caddy to the tile with such an adhesive strip, or replace your caddy with a 3M one attached to the tile with adhesive only.

[image: 3M Command strips]

(Image from amazon.com, used as an example only)

Answer (score 1):

Usually for tiled surfaces, you want a good suction cups.
Look for ones that have lever action - that is, you put them on a tile then move lever down to clamp them tight. These come in hook shape usually.

If hook is inadequate, look for tiny suction cup bathroom shelves, corner one should work well - they can be found in supermarkets and can hold a couple of shower utensils.

The tile surface might have soapy residue on it, so try cleaning it with brush/non-soap detergent before putting the suction elements on.